# Spring. Pass WebRequest to each method

Tags: java, spring, etag

I need to use spring `WebRequest` interface for check 
`request.checkNotModified(eTag)`

But I have to pass it into each method in my controller like

```
@GetMapping(value = "/url")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getData(@RequestHeader String header, WebRequest request)
```

is it possible to make something like

```
@Autowire 
WebRequest request
```

in class and then use it as request scope in each method in controller?

Comment: Take a look at [Filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible. You can inject `WebRequest` into the controllers due to this [configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3a0f309e2c9fdbbf7fb2d348be861528177f8555/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.java#L197) which is done during initialising the application context.

Comment: thanks. I was confused because Idea don't understand manually registered bean and can't found -> shows the error. but it works